# BadDirectoryException when zipping files

Tags: c#, zip

I tried zip all files in a folder, and save them to another folder.

**Error:**

> That name specifies an existing directory. Please specify a filename. Parameter Name: fileName

**AppConfig:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ZipLocation" value="c:\example\start"/>
    <add key="ZipSaveLocation" value="c:\example\extract"/>
</appSettings>
```

**Code:**

```
//using Ionic.Zip;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string startPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ZipLocation"].ToString();
    string zipPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ZipSaveLocation"].ToString();
    int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    try
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            String[] filenames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(startPath);

            foreach (String filename in filenames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding {0}...", filename);
                ZipEntry e = zip.AddFile(filename);
                e.Comment = "bla bla."; 
            }
            zip.Comment = String.Format("This zip archive was created by the CreateZip example application on machine '{0}'", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
            zip.Save(zipPath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not specified a file name, just a directory in which you want to save your file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
string zipPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ZipSaveLocation"].ToString();
```

and then you call this:

```
zip.Save(zipPath);
```

zipPath is not a file, it's a folder.

Fix your code by doing something like:

```
zip.Save(Path.Combine(zipPath,"newZipFile.zip"));
```

Comment: Really? First you ask me why on earth I would do this and then you copy it straight off?

Comment: Are you blind? How is your answer:  ZipEntry e = zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(filename, "myZipfile.zip"));

Even remotely close to mine? Are you trolling?

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a file not just a path:

just change `c:\example\extract` to `c:\example\extract\extract.zip` for example.

**Edit:**

Use the following:

```
zip.Save(Path.Combine(zipPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(startPath)));
```

Comment: I want to zip all files in start folder. start.zip save to c:\example\extract folder.How can I fix my code ?